# Angular 10 POST Request Directus Wav File upload

Tags: angular, directus

I am trying to upload a file to Directus (Headless CMS).
Here you will see the API description: https://docs.directus.io/api/files.html#create-a-file

I am working with Angular 10.

The file is a File which I get from Angular Frontend. It looks like this in the console:
File {name: "CantinaBand3.wav", lastModified: 1603486540829, lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 23 2020 22:55:40 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 132344, …}

```
uploadExampleTest(file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.url+"?access_token="+token, formData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}),
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.httpClient.request(req);
  }
```

With this I get : message: "data: This value should not be blank. filename_disk: This value should not be blank. filename_download: This value should not be blank."

```
 public uploadDirectus(file) {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var uuid = this.generateUUID(); //this makes just an uuid
    let postData = {
      "data": file,
      "filename_disk": uuid+".wav",
      "filename_download":  uuid+".wav"
    }
    var authorizationHeader = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  });
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, file, {  
        reportProgress: true,  
        observe: 'events',
        headers: authorizationHeader
      });  
  }
```

With this, I get the same error.

```
createFile(fileBase64,extension="png") {

    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var authorizationHeader = this.authService.getAuthorizationHeaderBrowser(token);
    var uuid = this.generateUUID();
    let postData = {
      "data": fileBase64,
      "filename_disk": uuid+"."+extension,
      "filename_download":  uuid+"."+extension
    }
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, postData, { headers: authorizationHeader,reportProgress: true,  observe: 'events' });
  }
```

With the last one I get : data: This value should not be blank. If I change it to Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' I get the same error as when I do the first 2 versions.

And this is the way I call it:

```
uploadFile(file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', file.data);
    formData.append('filename_disk', "ente.wav");
    formData.append('filename_download', "ente.wav");
    file.inProgress = true;
    console.log(formData);
    
    this.fileService.createFile(file.data,"wav").pipe(
      map(event => {
        switch (event.type) {
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            file.progress = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            return event;
        }
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
        file.inProgress = false;
        return of(`${file.data.name} upload failed.`);
      })).subscribe((event: any) => {
        if (typeof (event) === 'object') {
          console.log(event.body);
          this.link = event.body.link;
          console.log(event.body.link);
        }
      },error=>console.log(error));
  }
```